# Multiple Range Random Number Generator

Tags: java, random

Please help me out to generate random numbers based on the user input %'s.
For example, with input of 60,10 and 30, the output should be:

> 60% of random numbers of 0-70 range
>   10% of random numbers of 70-80
>   30% of random numbers of 80 above range

Should I use a multiple range generator?
or what all are the possibilities?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Random;

class RandomInRanges
{
    private final List<Integer> range = new ArrayList();

    RandomInRanges(int min, int max)
    {
        this.addRange(min, max);
    }

    final void addRange(int min, int max)
    {
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            this.range.add(i);
        }
    }

    int getRandom()
    {
        return this.range.get(new Random().nextInt(this.range.size()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RandomInRanges rir = new RandomInRanges(1, 200);
        rir.addRange(50, 60);
        System.out.println(rir.getRandom());
    }
}
```

Comment: You must demonstrate an minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: is your `?` key sticky? might want to see about cleaning your keyboard.

Comment: Where did the ranges (0-70, 70-80, 80+) come from? Is 70 in the first or second range? Do you want integers or something else? What's the maximum random number to be generated -- `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: That's actually a hard problem.  One needs to be fairly careful if one wants to both match the spec and avoid bias or patterns (other than the bias/patterns defined by the spec).

Comment: (But you need to tell us (and yourself) what the max value is, whether the values are int or float/double, and whether 70 and 80 are included in the lower range or the higher one.)

Answer (score 4):

A general approach might be as follows:

- Based on the frequencies, partition the unit interval (0, 1) into regions.
- Define a linear mapping from each partition element to the corresponding desired range.
- Generate random numbers uniformly distributed on (0, 1).
- Based on which part of (0, 1) each random number falls, apply the appropriate mapping.

Using your posted example, the ranges would be (0, .6), (.6, .7), (.7, 1). The first mapping would be from (0, .6) to (0, 70): y = 70 * x / 0.6. The second mapping would be from (0.6, 0.7) to (70, 80): y = 70 + 100 * (x - 0.6). The third mapping would require knowing the maximum number you want to generate.

The above works for continuous uniform distributions over several ranges. Note that the ranges are all open (which, for continuous distributions isn't an issue, since the probability of exactly hitting a boundary point is zero and ties can be resolved arbitrarily. If you want to do this for integer values, you can use the same approach and take the floor of the result. A bit of care needs to be taken to ensure that the endpoints are properly treated so as to avoid introducing bias.

Finally (hopefully it's obvious): this will only work if the desired output ranges are disjoint. For discrete distributions with contiguous ranges (as in your example), this would require deciding into which range each boundary point falls.